# Generating Swift files from templates

Tags: swift, metaprogramming

My goal is to create (find if exist) a tool which can produce swift files from templates.

For example, let’s say I need to create new ViewController with UITableView. It should be based on MVVM architecture with dependency injection. Let’s name this View “PersonsList”.

So, for this task I need to produce:

1. PersonListViewController
2. PersonListViewModel
3. PersonListViewModelProtocol
4. PersonCell
5. VM for cell and protocol for VM

Lots of files.

I want to say to my tool something like that

```
create tableview-template Person
```

and as a result get generated files. Files should contain empty implementation of each classes.

How should I do that? I am thinking about simple console app but I don’t know which language I should use. Maybe there is a better idea? Maybe there is a ready tool? Any help? :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell could you provide an example of usage `gyb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manually create the templates yourself and then write a short script (in Python / bash / swift etc) that goes through and replaces keywords with arguments you've passed in.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first idea. What do you think which language will be te best for this task? Is it depend only on my personal preferences? Also, could you provide any good example/tutorial how to create scripts on macOS? I don't know how to start with it.

Comment: Well if you have experience with swift then you could use that. It can be used as a scripting language. Otherwise those questions are too broad - you'll have to use Google sorry.